# javascript replace with submatch as array index

Tags: javascript

With a template:

```
<div id="temp" style="display:none;">
    <h3>{title}</h3>
    <p>{body}</p>
</div>
```

And script(jquery version):

```
var html = $('#temp').html();
var vals = {"title":"Hello","body":"Good bye!"};
html = html.replace(/{(.+?)}/g, vals["$1"]); // this works if replaced with code below
```

I get undefined for my replacements

the code below works but seems like it should work with one line as attempted above

```
matches = html.match(/{(.+?)}/g);  
for(m=0;m<matches.length;m++){
    var match=matches[m].replace("{","").replace("}", "");
    html = html.replace(matches[m],vals[match])
}
```

can this be simplified as desired?

this is too simple for a template engine so no need to go there.

Comment: The callback works like a champ, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may use callback as the second argument of [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
var result = html.replace(/{(.+?)}/g, function(c, m) { return vals[m]; });
```

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, that's why I deleted my answer :(

Comment: @mplungjan This is because there is no property `$1` in `vals` and the resulting value passed to `replace` will be `undefined`.